# Js function created from php not recognized

Tags: javascript, php, html

this is my php function

```
function php_html() {
    echo '
    <script>
        function getPicture(img) {
            var file = document.getElementById(img);
            file.click(); // open file
        }

        function onImgSelected(event) {
            var pieces = event.target.value.split("\\");
            var filename = pieces[pieces.length-1];
            if(event.target.id == "license_img") {
                document.getElementById("path_licenta_img").value = filename;
            } else {
                document.getElementById("path_car_img").value = filename;
            }
        }
    </script>

    <input type="file" style="display: none" accept="jpeg,jpg,png,bmp" id="car_pic" onChange="onImgSelected(event)" />
    <input type="file" style="display: none" accept="jpeg,jpg,png,bmp" id="license_img" onChange="onImgSelected(event)" />

    <button class="btn btn-default" onClick="getPicture(\'car_pic\')" type="button">Up</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" onClick="getPicture(\'license_img\')" type="button">Up</button>
    ';
}
```

When I click on Up button it throws error like this: **Uncaught ReferenceError: getPicture is not defined**  I see this in console.

What is wrong?

You can see [here][1] the exactlly problem.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're looking at console then how come you didn't see `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` on tax-register:107? That's your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking at console then how come you didn't see `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` on tax-register:107? That's your problem. In your code above you've put `var pieces = event.target.value.split("\\");`, but on your website you have `var pieces = event.target.value.split("\");`, you're not escaping the special character. This is breaking your JavaScript, and so your function is never defined.

In addition, if you're looking at the console, why haven't you done anything about `Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery`? Include jQuery.

Comment: Thank you man! You save my day... :D  (I'm new to web applications)